# Intermittent errors when complete or abandon service bus message

Tags: .net, azure, azureservicebus, brokeredmessage

> The request operation did not complete within the allotted timeout of 00:00:23.0285352. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout. TrackingId:24342fae-1f74-4eef-b8f6-3b05d8826835, Timestamp:8/24/2016 6:00:12 PM

And this

> Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessagingCommunicationException: Error during communication with Service Bus. Check the connection information, then retry. ---> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException: Internal Server Error: The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by a premature session shutdown. TrackingId:3896994a-fc09-4b95-9aa7-e82d81f5e596, Timestamp:8/24/2016 4:37:30 PM

What сould cause such errors?

Comment: Can you post more information on your pb? the context, the code anything that could be usefull... Otherwise the 1st problem seems to be due to the lock duration. how did you configure the lock duration? how long does it take to process your message ?

Comment: The 2nd exception leads me to think you'd want to investigate with MSFT what happened (using the tracking ID provided).

Comment: Is this still an error for you? I am guessing that you weren't able to reach the service at all (i.e. you had poor network connectivity).